# Sharpbox DropBoxTokenIssuer.exe tool not working, other tool for easy Dropbox access token creation?

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropbox-api

I would like to use the **DropBoxTokenIssuer** tool which comes with SharpBox, for easy creation of app access to a Dropbox account, but it does not work atm.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix it, or know of a different tool which does the same.

Answer (score 2):

For answer please refer following URL...

http://sharpbox.codeplex.com/workitem/18848

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [DropNet](https://github.com/dkarzon/DropNet) (also on [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/dropnet)) with great success.  The GitHub notes provide good sample code for getting through the Dropbox authorization workflow.